# minikube - How to know the name of the minikube VM being used?

Tags: minikube

I want to use `minikube ssh [flags]` command

There is Global Flag:

> -p, --profile string                   The name of the minikube VM being used.

So, I need to know the name of the minikube VM. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/) is a tool that makes it easy to run Kubernetes locally. Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a VM on your laptop for users looking to try out Kubernetes or develop with it day-to-day.

Parameter  "-p", that you mentioned, is used to name the VM where minikube creates a Kubernetes stack. Omitting this parameter presupposes default value "minikube".

For the system running minikube with the support of the VirtualBox:

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
```

First returned value is the name of minikube instance. I assume there is no other
VirtualBox session running.

Next, you can use this name to:

```
minikube ssh <name>
```

When you create minikube with -p parameter, to manage this setup you must use -p  
with every  minikube command call. This parameter is useful for multiple minikube instances running on the same host.

Answer (score 5):

Profiles feature on some stacks are broken since 0.26.0, and still with version 0.28.2. [#2818](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2818), [#2574](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2574#issuecomment-418921655)

Without setting a profile the default profile will create a VM called "minikube".

```
minikube profile default
minikube profile was successfully set to minikube
```

Set the profile to another name,

```
minikube profile experiment
```

then view the profile set with

```
minikube config view
```

and create a new Minikube VM with that profile name

```
minikube start --profile experiment
```

With the profile set to "experiment", the VM created in VirtualBox will (should) be named "experiment".